# Apple Time Machine: Don't have sufficient privileges

Tags: networking

I follow [these instructions](http://garmoncheg.blogspot.de/2012/11/time-capsule-for-25.html)

But I stopped at the very last step. I am asked twice to give user/pass: First, when I connect to the shared "TimeMachine Pi" (all good);

[image]

Then, after adding the RPi as capsule I am told

[image]

Comment: Can the Pi read/write directly to the disk?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I cannot help but wonder why you would want to do this. I find a directly attached disk using Firewire 800 slow enough, let alone over the network. Initial backup can take hours.

However, I would suggest that you first attempt the access the disk from Finder using Appletalk. I use

```
open afp://10.1.1.10
```

but substitute the IP address of your Pi.

You will be prompted for the Pi username and password. You can then opt to save these in your keychain, so future logon is easier.

Comment: The advantage of wireless backup is that it happens invisibly.  You don't have to do anything to make it happen and it just takes the time it needs! No messing with cables and having to wait for it to finish! The convenience level is comparable to a television _with_ a remote compared to one _without_.  I bought a time capsule just for that and fully understand those who would like a more humanely priced solution.